# maven was6:installApp TransferFailed

Tags: deployment, connection, websphere, file-transfer

I'm trying to deploy my ear to a remote Websphere 8.5 with maven plugin was6 via SOAP.
I set up the correct ear with correct host, node,cell,server, port etc.

But when I try to install app I got WASX7017E: ConnectException - Connection refused with a TransferFailedException

In logs, there is nothing in local and remote neither. As I see with netstat when I run the mvn installApp there are many connection trying on serverside whiches have status TIME_WAIT.

The plugin seems to be working with v8.5 cause other functions for example wsListApp work.
I tried to google it but with no results.

Does anyone get this error before me? Or has anyone idea what should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

was6-maven-plugin generates a temporal ant file under "target\was6-maven-plugin\" folder and then calls $WAS_HOME\bin\ws_ant.sh/bat utility using -f option with the previously generated ant file.

If you don't use the clean target, the files should continue there so you can use ws_ant to find the real error and find if there is an error on your configuration or in the plugin.

If you find an error in the plugin, please open an issue here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWAS

In this link you'll find all the options available in the wsInstallApp target:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fweb%2Fapidocs%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fwebsphere%2Fant%2Ftasks%2FInstallApplication.html

Regards,

Javier Murciego